# Flutter autofill password with 1password not working for Android devices

Tags: android, flutter, autofill, 1password

```
AutofillGroup(
      child: Column(children: [
        AutofillGroup(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(autofillHints: [
              AutofillHints.username,
            ]),
            TextField(autofillHints: [
              AutofillHints.password,
            ]),
          ],
        )),
      ]),
    );
```

With Google password manager it's working good, but not with 1password.

If email textfield pressed it's showing the 1password prompt but password never autofill.
If password textfield is pressed the 1pass prompt not showing.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue. The iCloud Keychain can autofill just fine, but nothing works with 1Password. I did come across this https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/iqwjn7/1password_beta_adds_support_for_flutter_autofill/ It is a year old, but im wondering if its still relevant today. So far, nothing works in Chrome or Safari.

Comment: Here is the thread talking with 1Password people
https://1password.community/discussion/127475/autofill-password-field-not-triggering-on-android-devices-for-flutter#latest